# Probability of me being one of a group

Tags: probability

I've heard that in a certain country with a population of about 140,000,000, 200 people become missing on a daily basis. If I want to calculate the random probability that one of those people would be, say, me, would it be correct to do it as follows?

$\frac{140000000 \choose 1}{140000000 \choose 200}$

I'm puzzled because the probability seems too small.

Comment: What you have done does not seem correct. The total sample space is 140 million, out of which 200 people are picked. What is the chance that you are among those ? So shouldn't it be 200 divided by 140 mil ?

Comment: Correct, it's much more simple than it seemed. Thank you